only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC, but i'm deploying a smart contract
I made a spring boot application with web3j, in application.properties i have defined the following:
spring.application.name=Web3j-1
ethereum.private-key=myprivatekey
ethereum.provider=https://eth.public-rpc.com

this is the main code:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class Web3jConfig {
    @Value("${ethereum.provider}")
    private String ethereumProvider;
    @Value("${ethereum.private-key}")
    private String ethereumPrivateKey;

    @Bean
    public Web3j web3j() {
        return Web3j.build(new HttpService(ethereumProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public Credentials credentials() {
        return Credentials.create(ethereumPrivateKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public CounterContract counterContract() {
        CounterContract counterContract;
        try {
            SignedRawTransaction transaction;
            counterContract = CounterContract.deploy(web3j(), credentials(), new DefaultGasProvider()).send();
            // counter = Counter.load(counterContractAddress, web3j(), credentials(), new DefaultGasProvider());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while deploying a contract", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        log.info("Counter contract has been deployed: {}", counterContract.getContractAddress());
        return counterContract;
    }
}

the deploy function being used:
public static RemoteCall<CounterContract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(CounterContract.class, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider, getDeploymentBinary(), "");
    }

I've looked around and people talk about integrating the chainID, but i'm seeing this for transactions, not smart contract deployments. What should i do in this case? Right now i'm just trying to deploy the contract itself, then i will make transactions to that contract with the chainID.
